# Application special access Wi-Fi control is blocked on Verizon Samsung Galaxy No 10+

Tags: applications, samsung, wi-fi, settings, permissions

I have a Samsung Galaxy Note 10+ (Verizon, unrooted). I am unable to disable the application's access to WiFi control. I could in the past.

In Settings - Apps - Special access - Wi-Fi control, all apps are ticked and blocked.

Why? Can this be fixed?

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. Could you describe more about the apps? Are they Samsung apps or do they include 3rd-party apps? Checking my Galaxy M12, looks like some of the system apps can't be disabled. Otherwise, you may want to check if there are active Device admin apps that may lock the settings.

Comment: Is your wifi enabled when you are doing this ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.